# Boundary condition for stochastic differential equation

Tags: random, stochastic-calculus

I have a simple stochastic differential equation (SDE) with white noise:

```
mysde[q_, I_, n0_, sd_] := 
  ItoProcess[
    \[DifferentialD]n[t] == 
      ( I - q n[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + sd \[DifferentialD]w[t], n[t], 
    {n, n0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

I want to impose a condition that n[t] cannot fall below zero. At below zero, or an arbitrarily low value of n[t], it is considered zero. I am not sure how to implement this in the ItoProcess function and/or in the numerical solution:

```
sol[q_, I_, n0_, sd_] := RandomFunction[mysde[q, I, n0, sd], {0, 100, 0.1}, 1]
```

The variable drops below zero many times, which is not a desired behaviour:

```
With[{q = 2, I = 0.1, n0 = 1, sd = 0.1}, 
  Show[ListLinePlot[sol[q, I, n0, sd]], ImageSize -> 400]]
```

What are some ways to implement such a condition?

I have tried various functions on `n[t]` within the `ItoProcess[]`, to attempt to re-set negative values of `n[t]` to zero, like `If[]`, `Max[]`, `Clip[]`, and `Piecewise[]` to no avail. Any reasons why these functions do not dynamically work within the solver?

Also is there a way to extract the values of the noise, `w[t]`, in a particular simulated path of the temporal data timeseries object?

One potential solution, which is not confirmed to be correct, is to write the equation for the log of my variable, `ln[t]` and to use the Geometric Brownian motion random process formulation, obtaining:

```
logsde[q_, I_, ln0_, sd_] := 
  ItoProcess[
    \[DifferentialD]ln[t] == 
      ( I - q ln[t] - sd^2/2) \[DifferentialD]t + sd \[DifferentialD]w[t], ln[t], 
   {ln, ln0}, t, w \[Distributed] GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[I - q ln[t], sd, n0]]

logsol[q_, I_, ln0_, sd_] := RandomFunction[logsde[q, I, ln0, sd], {0, 100, 0.1}, 1]
```

Then I extract the simulated values, and exponentiate them to obtain the time series or path in the original scale:

```
td = With[{q = 0.1, I1 = 0.1, ln0 = 1, sd = .1}, 
  logsol[q, I1, ln0, sd]];
ListLinePlot[Exp[td["States"]]]
```

However I have lost the stochastic signal in this model; the simulation smooths out and looks continuous with no noise, except at the beginning of the simulation. This is obviously an incorrect formulation. What did I do here? How might I formulate this properly?

Are there other approaches?

So overall I have three questions:

1. How to implement a boundary condition in `ItoProcess[]` for one of
   the state variables?
2. How to recover the simulated values of the random variable? <- self-answered below
3. How to properly specify a log-transformed version of the `ItoProcess[]`?

Comment: What is  the mathematical model of "not below zero"? Say, should it bounce or once zero is always zero? Or It just needed to draw a plot, where the negative part is turned to aero?

Comment: I disagree with your statement that "is not supposed to happen in this model"; the solution to your top SDE is a normally distributed random variable with parameters you can get with `Mean[mysde[q, ii, n0, sd][t]]` and `StandardDeviation[mysde[q, ii, n0, sd][t]]` so yes, it can go negative.

Comment: b.gatessucks you are right, the model as specified, it does happen. However, I want to impose the condition that the variable n[t] cannot go below zero (or an arbitrarily small value). The question is how to modify the equation or include a condition in the model that would prevent negative values from occuring.

Comment: To answer Andrew's question, the variable should be able to recover from zero.

Comment: Would taking the absolute value of $n$ do?

Comment: Unfortunately the absolute value would not work for the model. In a given time interval, the state variables cannot go below zero. So I want to "floor" negative values to zero in any interval the stock is "overdrawn". I have tried imposing If, Piecewise, and Max statements on n[t], but I do not know how to implement them dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

This an answer of question 2, "How to recover the simulated values of the random variable?":

Just specify the random variable in the state vector argument. For example,

```
mysde[q_, I1_, n0_, sd_] := ItoProcess[
{\[DifferentialD]n[t] == 
( -q n[t]) \[DifferentialD]t + I1 \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, 
{n[t], I1 + w[t]}, {n, n0}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, sd]]
```

This sink population has white noise inputs with mean, `I1`, and standard deviation, `sd`. The state vector is argument `x` taken by the `ItoProcess` function, `{n[t], I1 + w[t]}` here. The distribution of inputs is the stochastic variable, `I1 + w[t]`, which I am interested in.

So simulate the stochastic model with initial condition and parameters:

```
sol[q_, I1_, n0_, sd_] := RandomFunction[mysde[q, I1, n0, sd], {0, 1000, 0.1}, 1]
td = With[{q = 1, I1 = 0.1, n0 = 0.1, sd = 0.01}, sol[q, I1, n0, sd]];
```

The object `td` gives the solution for a stochastic simulation. A run of all the variables may be visualized as a time series:

```
ListLinePlot[td]
```

Extract the time series of just one of the variables, the stochastic forcing variable in this case, with,

```
stochvar = td["States"][[1]][[All, 1]]]
```

Do what you want with the data, for example:

```
Histogram[stochvar]
Mean[stochvar]
Variance[stochvar]
```

I am sure there are more elegant approaches, but hopefully this provides a good example for some basics of the SDE functions in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that `n[t]` cannot fall below zero is an inherent part of a solution algorithm that is applied for a numerical SDE solution and preserves a positivity of solution domain.

Typically, such problem is solved by using of **implicit** numerical solution. 
Currently, Mathematica has a support only for **explicit** methods for `ItoProcess` command (the [brief explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_and_implicit_methods) about the difference between analogous methods for non-stochastic DE).

For example, the implicit [Milstein method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method) for SDE of the form

$\mathrm{d} X_t = a(X_t) \, \mathrm{d} t + b(X_t) \, \mathrm{d} W_t$

is given by (may be compared to explicit one in the link above)

$Y_{n + 1} = Y_n + a(Y_{n+1}) \Delta t + b(Y_n) \Delta W_n + \frac{1}{2} b(Y_n) b'(Y_n) \left( (\Delta W_n)^2 - \Delta t \right)$

and, sometimes, after some basic math may be implemented by `RecurrenceTable` command as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99766/random-variable-in-recurrence-function). At more complex case, each iteration step has to be solved numerically...

Additional information may be found, for example, in Ch. 12 of Kloeden & Platen, "Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations", 3rd, Springer, 1999.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. I will look into this over the next several weeks.